# Define multiple tcolorboxes from list of names

Tags: tcolorbox, loops, preamble

I recently build this little tcolorbox for a template:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{book}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{framedboxfilled/.style={
        sharp corners,
        fonttitle={\bfseries},
        coltitle=black,
        toprule=1pt, bottomrule=1pt, titlerule=1pt,
        leftrule=0pt, rightrule=0pt,
    }
}
\tcbset{framedboxoutline/.style={%  
        framedboxfilled, colback=white,colbacktitle=white,
    }
}
\def\myboxstyle{framedboxoutline}% To be set by a class option
\newtcolorbox[auto counter,number within=section]{framedbox}[2][]{%
    \myboxstyle, title={#2}, #1
}

\begin{document}
\begin{framedbox}{Title}
    test
\end{framedbox}
\end{document}
```

Now I want to include a list of strings, e.g.:

```
\newcommand{\framedboxValues}{
    Example/example, Homework/homework,
}
```

This list should contain all names for the resulting tcolorboxes. The first value is for the title, the second value for the LaTeX command. What I want to archive is, that there is some kind of for-loop that takes the values in the list and creates the boxes with the style above. Sadly I have no idea how to archive that. My work so far resulted in this code snippet, that does not really work:

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \defframedthms { m }
{ \clist_map_inline:nn {#1} { \defframedthm {##1} } }
\NewDocumentCommand \defframedthm { > { \SplitArgument { 1 } { / } } m }
{
% Create the tcolorboxes

}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\expandafter\defframedthms\expandafter{\framedboxValues}
```

I tried several things to create those tcolorboxes, but none of them worked. Can someone help me do that?

**EDIT:**

I made some progress, but still don't have a good solution. So far I have this:

```
\newcommand\framedthm[3]{
    \newtcolorbox[auto counter,number within=section]{#2}[2][]{%
        \myboxstyle,
        title={#1 \thetcbcounter~##1},
    }
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \defframedthms { m }
{ \clist_map_inline:nn {#1} { \defframedthm {##1} } }
\NewDocumentCommand \defframedthm { > { \SplitArgument { 1 } { / } } m }
{ \framedthm #1 { } }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\expandafter\defframedthms\expandafter{\framedboxValues}
```

The remaining problems: I can not add a title for the boxes. I can't parse individual changes to the box. So e.g. `\begin{box}[colback = red]{Title}...` includes all problems I know so far (There is no title and the color is still white). But `\begin{box}[title]...` works, but without individual options for the tcolorbox.

Comment: I'm not sure about the indirection with the command for the list: is there any need for it?

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?  Here, I parse the argument to `\framedboxvalues` and create environments for each item in the list.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{book}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{framedboxfilled/.style={
        sharp corners,
        fonttitle={\bfseries},
        coltitle=black,
        toprule=1pt, bottomrule=1pt, titlerule=1pt,
        leftrule=0pt, rightrule=0pt,
    }
}
\tcbset{framedboxoutline/.style={%  
        framedboxfilled, colback=white,colbacktitle=white,
    }
}
\def\myboxstyle{framedboxoutline}% To be set by a class option
\newtcolorbox[auto counter,number within=section]{framedbox}[2][]{%
    \myboxstyle, title={#2}, #1
}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\setsepchar[*]{,*/}
\newcommand\makemyenv[2]{%
  \newenvironment{#2}{\begin{framedbox}{#1}}{\end{framedbox}}%
}
\newcommand\framedboxValues[1]{%
  \ignoreemptyitems
  \readlist*\fbvalues{#1}%
  \def\tmp{}%
  \def\zz{\noexpand\zz}%
  \foreachitem\z\in\fbvalues[]{%
    \edef\tmp{\tmp\noexpand\zz
      {\fbvalues[\zcnt,1]}{\fbvalues[\zcnt,2]}
    }%
  }%
  \let\zz\makemyenv
  \tmp
}

\begin{document}
\framedboxValues{
    Example/example, Homework/homework
}
\begin{example}
    test
\end{example}
\begin{homework}
    test
\end{homework}
\end{document}
```

[image]